# How to set a breakpoint and then show the data After running the programm with pwndbg?

Tags: debugging, binary, gdb, breakpoints, disassembly

Im learning how to use pwndbg and I want to know how to set a breakpoint and then after running the programm it shows the stack, Register etc. Like Crypto Cat did. And I want to make that as well but I dont know how. I installed pwndbg but It seems different. Can anyone help?